# SQL Union query that produces Data Type Mismatch error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I created the following query in Access 2007-2010

```
SELECT [Zip Code Count].[Zip Code], [Zip Code Count].CountOfAddress1
FROM [Zip Code Count]
WHERE [Zip Code Count].[Zip Code] NOT IN (Select [Zip Code List].[Zip Code] From [Zip Code List])

UNION  

Select [Covered Zips Count].[Zip Code], [Covered Zips Count].CountOfAddress1
FROM [Covered Zips Count]
Where [Covered Zips Count].CountOfAddress1 < 10;
```

The `Covered Zip Counts` and `Zip Code Count` are both aggregate queries from a larger (800+ record) set of data. `Zip Code List` is a simple table of specific zip codes.

What I am trying to do is to make a list of those zip codes that are not in the `Zip Code List` plus those zip codes which are in the list but the total count of records is less than 10 (this is necessary for bulk mailing via the postal service).

I get the following error.

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Both query parts on their own work perfectly fine. The output of both queries is exactly the same: the Zip codes are text and the Counts are integers. This query seems like it should just work but it refuses to.

Comment: What are the datatypes of columns `[Zip Code Count].[Zip Code]` and `[Covered Zips Count].[Zip Code]` ? They need to be the same. Also, `[Zip Code Count].CountOfAddress1` and `[Covered Zips Count].CountOfAddress1` need to have the same datatype.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem...well sort of. I attempted to make separate queries and then union them in another query. That gave me the same error, so I tried to remove one of the fields. Then I got the error "Query is too complex". So I am guessing that the software couldn't handle it.

I ended up turning the original aggregation query of zip codes into a Make Table query. Once I had a solid set of data, the UNION query I tried in the first place worked perfectly.